# What does the killing in "Killing Eve" mean?

Tags: adjectives

There is a TV show named "Killing Eve" and its Chinese translation basically means Eve is killed or to kill Eve. But I wonder whether killing can be an adjective here to describe the state or action of Eve. And it means Eve is killing others.
1. Eve is killed. / To kill Eve.
2. Eve is killing other people.
Which one is right? Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Kill" has many, many possible interpretations.

Comment: I would have thought had they intended it to mean the other way they would have called it "Eve the killer" or "murderous Eve". Actually Murderous Eve sounds good, sounds like a horror story on the day before Christmas.

Comment: @Mia Another interpretation would be that it is the eve (evening) of killings to come.  The writer likely wanted a title that would convey multiple meanings.

Comment: It could also have another meaning.  "Killing" can mean to do something to perfection.  So the title could refer to someone portraying Eve perfectly or a story that conveys the essence of Eve or tells her story exceptionally well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### "Killing" can be an adjective or present participle

You are correct; "killing" can be used as an adjective (or as a present participle—in many contexts, it is difficult to distinguish participles from adjectives) to describe something or someone that kills. An example is the phrase *[killing frost](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/killing-frost)*, which refers to "frost that kills".

So the English phrase "Killing Eve" is technically ambiguous.

But I would say that the interpretation where "killing" is a gerund, and "Eve" is the object of the gerund (the one who is killed) strikes me as more natural, so it makes  sense to me that the Chinese translation is based on that parse of the title.

### Either interpretation would be "correct" in terms of grammar

There is no way to use the rules of English grammar to determine which interpretation of "Killing Eve" is "right". You could ask the person who came up with the title to tell you the originally intended interpretation, but not everyone would agree that this should be considered the only correct interpretation of the title. Translators often don't have access to this information. (See the answers to this Movies & TV SE question about [the translation of the ambiguous movie title "The Last Jedi"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84846).)

Comment: When I read *Killing Eve*, I thought it was the eve *of* or *for* killing. Like it was the time to kill stuff. When it doesn't occur to you that *Eve* is  a personal name, other parses spring to mind.